# Automapper for DTO to Domain

Tags: ef-code-first, automapper, code-first, dto

I have domain like this

```
 public class Person 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Gender gender  { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

the Gender property of the person is lookup... which mean from the UI the user select the Gender as drop-down

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int personid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int genderid  { get; set; }
}
```

so how do I setup my AutoMapper... to convert the DTO to Domain and vice verse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, AutoMapper provides object flattening out-of-the-box, so this will be done automatically for you.

```
Person person = new Person();
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, EmployeeDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.personid, opt =>
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.id));   // this line is only because I noticed different property names (id vs personid)
EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = Mapper.Map<EmployeeDTO>(person);
employeeDTO.genderid.ShouldEqual(person.gender.id);
```

If you use the convention `OuterProperty.InnerProperty` in your complex domain object, and the types match properly, AutoMapper will flatten it down to `OuterPropertyInnerProperty` in the destination object. You can read all about that here: http://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening